# PHP Soap / Java

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap

I have a co-worker who worked on Web Service with Java (I think it was with Axis).
My collegue created some java classes and for now we use them in a DOS windows and a .bat.

My boss asked me if it was possible to use these java classes with PHP Soap.
I know PHP but I never used Soap, so i'm kinda stuck.

For example, we have a java class to read some objects with 3 arguments.
We had imagine in PHP to create a form with 3 fields, retrieve those 3 fields then call the java class (example : readO($var1, $var2, $var3)).

Is this possible to do that with PHP Soap with minimum change from java class ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with any changes of the classes, that's the idea of the WSs, the client just need to use the right namespaces and config.

Comment: Ty for your answer. I succeed to __getFunctions() from my wsdl. Now I wanted to know how to do to call a java function which is out of the wsdl :/

Comment: If the function is not part of the wsdl operations, you can't call it.